# HTML5 Gaussian blur effect

Tags: webkit

How is apple able to achieve the (apparent) Gaussian blur effect for the photos in the background in this demo:

[http://www.apple.com/html5/showcase/gallery/](https://web.archive.org/web/20140420060736/http://www.apple.com/html5/showcase/gallery)

Comment: your link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source, those are prerendered. No HTML5 trickery for that part, unfortunately.

Example: http://images.apple.com/html5/showcase/gallery/images/polo9b-small.png

Comment: Aw, that's no fun. Interestingly, it looks like it swaps them by setting one of their opacities to 0 rather than setting visibility to hidden (or display to none).

Answer (score 28):

Now we are in 2012, look a this:

http://css-plus.com/2012/03/gaussian-blur/

and this:

http://blurjs.com/

Comment: Second link is broken.

Answer (score 11):

In case you want to do something similar with Canvas, check out [StackBlur](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html). Works great! I know it's not Gaussian blur but it should be close enough. :)