# Is there any way to blur all page and focus certain div with jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, focus, blur

Is there any way to blur all page (for example set new background and give it to the foreground with z-index) and focus certain div (let's say error message) with jquery/javascript? Do you know any plugin for that purpose?

That's what I wanna get:

[image]

Comment: Only with HTML5, this was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975089/html5-gaussian-blur-effect)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the jQuery UI dialog and use CSS to change the overlay div background with a blur background image, like here:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/BlurryBackgroundEffect/

--or--

You can use the jQuery UI dialog mixed with the CSS Text blur effect found here:

http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/04/blur-effect-with-css-and-jquery.html

However, I assume this will NOT be backwards compatible with non-html5 browsers.

Here's a JS fiddle for proof of concept:  http://jsfiddle.net/khalifah/vgGtK/

Here's one with the style I think you want: http://jsfiddle.net/khalifah/7L5jG/

Comment: This is not bad, think I will be using this on a project I currently working on. Will fall back to the grayed out transparency for older browsers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/khalifah/7L5jG/ works well but first doesn't. Can we animate the message box and make it modal like in theese examples http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message  ??

Comment: And what if there is not only text but text and images on the page? How can we blur all images and texts (for html 5 ready browsers) and fall back to something like theese examples http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example4/index.html# in case old browsers?

Comment: Blurring images... you could do something like this, which I don't recommend: http://simurai.com/post/716453142/css3-image-blur. However, it better to use an blurring overlay image.

Comment: Can you animate the message box, make it modal (like in theese examples http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message) and add this css3 blur effect (for both images and texts) to your solution on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/khalifah/7L5jG)?  And fall back to something like theese examples  http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example4/index.html# in case old browsers. I'll be gratefull if you'll do it. Thank you in advance