# Blur effect on a div element

Tags: html, css, blur

Is it possible to add a gaussian blur on `div` element? If yes, how I can do this?

Comment: What have you found so far? Have you googled this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Gaussian blur effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975089/html5-gaussian-blur-effect)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply a CSS 3 blur filter to a background image that I am setting with background-image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image-that-i-am-setting-with-ba)

Answer (score 186):

I think this is what you are looking for? If you are looking to add a blur effect to a div element, you can do this directly through CSS Filters-- See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ayhj9vb0/

```css
div {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed.

Answer (score 11):

you can do quite a few things :

1. `filter: blur(10px)`
2. `backdrop-filter: blur(10px)`
3. If you want to blur the edges of the div element, use box-shadow

   `box-shadow: 10px 20px 20px grey;`

the third value of 20px sets the blur value. The bigger the value, the more the blur.

You can use either of these, although do note that `backdrop-filter` doesn't have browser support for firefox and internet explorer.

Answer (score 8):

Try using this library:  https://github.com/jakiestfu/Blur.js-II

That should do it for ya.

Comment: It has bugs with chrome + it slow page load.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I found:

Demo: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemBlur/

and Tutorial: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/14/item-blur-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/

Answer (score 5):

I got blur working with SVG blur filter:

**CSS**

```css
-webkit-filter: url(#svg-blur);
filter: url(#svg-blur);
```

**SVG**

```
<svg id="svg-filter">
    <filter id="svg-blur">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/1k5x6dgm/

Please note - this will not work in IE versions

Answer (score 4):

Blurring the background elements of a div can be achieved using `backdrop-filter`.

Use it like this:

```css
.your-class-name {
   backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

All the elements placed under the div are going be blurred by using this.

EDIT: Notice that this is not supported by every browser yet

Answer (score 4):

Inline css:

```css
style="filter: blur(3px);"
```

External css with class:

```css
.div-cls{
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

Having major browser support too [ [1](https://caniuse.com/?search=filter) ].